# Twilio : Get details of Call by Number array: PHP

Tags: twilio, twilio-php

I want to get call details of bunch of From twilio numbers. I am using PHP-Twilio library. Here is my code,

```
$array = array('num1','num2');

foreach ($client->account->calls->getIterator(0, 10, array(
    'From' => $array
)) as $call) { }
```

But its not working. It returns everything.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I'm afraid [the Calls endpoint only takes one "From" number as a filter](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/call#list-get-filters), you can't pass a list of numbers to it. You might want to return all calls and then filter manually yourself or alternatively loop through the numbers you want to return calls from and make list calls for each of them.

Comment: Thanks for replying. Actually it is really slow, so I thought of supplying From number. I will try supplying multiple `From`
Do you have any workaround in mind? Its kind of Admin Panel and only few Twilio number details is needed.